# YouTube playsinline attribute

Tags: cordova, youtube-api

```
window.player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {

  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '200',
    videoId: 'sdfsdfasd',
    playerVars: {'playsinline': 1},
    events: {
      'onReady': app.onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': app.onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': app.onPlayerError
    }
  });
```

In my Cordova iOS app, I set YouTube iframe's playsinline attribute as 1 when the player is ready. However, when I play a video the player goes full screen. There is a post in Google group for YouTube API that says there's an inssue with `playsinline` attribute right now and it doesn't work.

The attribute works fine in a simulator, but it doesn't work on a real device. How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I edited the source code inside webViewDidFinishLoad. From below

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

I added `theWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES; // <- added
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```